# When Open Excel file made by C#, occurring infinite loading. How to solve it?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I made an excel file in C# and saved it automatically.

If dragging the excel file to an already opened excel .. It opens very well and I can edit it right away.

But If excel is turned off and I open the file with double click,
the file is open and its contents are visible, but the mouse is infinitely loaded and cannot be edited.
(In the meantime, with the mouse wheel, the up/down window can be moved. just it.)

How can I solve it about infinite loading even if I open it?

```
Excel.Application excelApp = null;
Excel.Workbook wb;
Excel.Worksheet ws1;

excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
excelApp.Visible = true; 

excelApp.Interactive = false;

wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

ws1 = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

wb.SaveAs(@filePath+Name+".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);

[contents about Cell value, and making template]

excelApp.Interactive = true;

ws1.Activate();
wb.Save();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws1);

GC.Collect();
```

Comment: _"But If excel is turned off and I open the file with double click ... cannot be edited"_ - as a test, prior to double-clicking the file from Windows Explorer check that there are no invisible instances of Excel running in Task Manager.  Kill them if so.  I suspect what might be happening is that an invisible dialog is appearing blocking normal operation

Comment: `excelApp.Interactive = false;` I suspect if you get an exception after this point you will experience what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone.
I checked the Task Manager as MickyD Said, and found that there are some excel tasks . So I Kill them. After killing, It's open very well. 
I thinks I got an exception after excelApp.Interactive = false; as mjwills said.
I need to study more about killing task for memory.  Thanks a lot.